# Query string with unreliable/irregular structure (with LINQ?)

Tags: c#, string, linq, parsing, rtsp

I'm currently trying to parse RTSP messages that usually look like the example in the code field below (taken from RF2326). But I'm running into several problems because of a somehow irregular structure of the messages, also weakly defined delimiters etc.

Some thoughts on this:

- Stepping through the string line by line: But what if a command/parameter is split over two lines?
- Splitting the lines by certain chars for key/value parsing -> I have to be sure that the first occurence of e.g. ':' is the delimiter for key/value.
- Splitting the lines by spaces (" ") - but also lines like CSeq:312 (without space) can occur.

Also: I can only assume that the header part (until Content-Length in example) is seperated from the body by to breaks (`\r\n`). What if there is only one?

Is there a way to solve this elegant and reliable? Maybe with LINQ?

- Client -> Server:

  ```
  DESCRIBE rtsp://server.example.com/fizzle/foo RTSP/1.0
  CSeq: 312
  Accept: application/sdp, application/rtsl, application/mheg
  ```
- Server -> Client:

  ```
  RTSP/1.0 200 OK
  CSeq: 312
  Date: 23 Jan 1997 15:35:06 GMT
  Content-Type: application/sdp
  Content-Length: 376

  v=0
  o=mhandley 2890844526 2890842807 IN IP4 126.16.64.4
  s=SDP Seminar
  i=A Seminar on the session description protocol
  u=http://www.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/M.Handley/sdp.03.ps
  e=mjh@isi.edu (Mark Handley)
  c=IN IP4 224.2.17.12/127
  t=2873397496 2873404696
  a=recvonly
  m=audio 3456 RTP/AVP 0
  m=video 2232 RTP/AVP 31
  m=whiteboard 32416 UDP WB
  a=orient:portrait
  ```

Comment: What do you want your output to look like?

Comment: If I were "playing around" I would use Regex to parse the response. In your regexes you may compensate optional spaces / linebreaks etc.
Perhaps you could create an abstract class for response and subclasses for different response types?

Comment: BTW, the wikipedia article on RTSP looks decent: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol

Answer (score 0):

You can use my library to parse SDP...

Check it out @ https://net7mma.codeplex.com/

There is also an article explaining it here ->
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507218/Managed-Media-Aggregation-using-Rtsp-and-Rtp

Let me know if you need anything else!